# How can I have one long edge for object that has random edges and subdivision cuts?

Tags: modeling

My Building object has random edges or subdivision cuts. When I extrude one face there's multiple faces/subdivisions. How can it be one long edge?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can upload images directly into your question, don't use external sites for this. And it won't hurt to form at least one sentence in your question. Apart from that, if you select all in _Edit Mode_ hit M > _Merge_ > _By Distance_ and then maybe hit X > _Limited Dissolve_ this might help.

Comment: It looks as if you have way too many vertices for this shape. Try X > 'Limited Dissolve', to keep only the ones that matter.

Comment: @RobinBetts _Limited Dissolve_, oh yeah someone should have written that before :D